# Dragon naturally speaking Activex class not found

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe3, naturallyspeaking

I am currently working on some old (Delphi) source code that was provided to me. I am currently trying restore any libraries that the old code needed. One such dependency is to define "DNSTools_TLB" library.

I found out that the prefix "_TLB" was when Delphi imported/added an ActiveX library, so I imported the Dragon Activex library on to my code.

After this I still get an error saying "Class TDgnDictCustom not found" (other DNS classes called do not get this error)

I also tried renaming the class TDgnDictCustom both in the source code and library but the problem still persists.

Can I please get some help on how to to resolve/trace this error..

ps: this is my first post here so please let me know if i broke any rules.

EDIT:Here is the error I get
"Class TDgnDictCustom not found. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE: Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values to be lost"

Comment: Are you using the same version as before? When you imported it, did you replace the existing wrapper unit, or create a different unit?

Comment: Are you importing the same versions of Dragon naturally speaking ActiveX as the code was designed for? If you are importing newer version it is possible that the AIP was changed (new functionality added, other functions becoming obsolete, etc.) to a point where your code won't even work any more.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Don't paraphrase error messages, reproduce them verbatim.

Comment: @SilverWarior I am using the same version as before. Since it used the same version I did not check the API...

Comment: @jerryDodge no i did not change anything, just imported the ActiveX library.

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Edit the question and put the information there.

Comment: But the error is clear enough. There is no designtime component with that name registered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added the error to the post, thank you for pointing it out to me.
When i add the ActiveX component, It shows a list of classes that are included. and "TDgnDictCustom"  is said to be included in it. but when I compile the code it is not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Class TDgnDictCustom not found. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE: Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values to be lost.

This error is reported by the form designer when it tries to open a form, and the form references a component that has not been registered with the IDE. What it tells you is that the .dfm file contains a reference to an instance of the class `TDgnDictCustom` but that no design time package has registered that class.

You would resolve this by working out which design time package is missing from your IDE, and installing it. You might need to create a design time package yourself. Or the original developer of your program may already have done that. It's a little hard to be more specific with what we know.